# Pre-Made Cables & Headers for (Parallel Interface) GLCD's

Tags: distributors, cable-assemblies, ribbon-cable, glcd

Is it possible to buy Pre-Made cables & headers to suit GLCD's, the model Im using has a 20-Pin interface like the model in the image below.

If as I fear such a convience does not exist what do you use/have you found to be the neatest way to connect these?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up buying these and some pin headers from ebay. Not the prettiest solution but probably the handiest.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A place I used to work at connected a graphic LCD to the main board with what looked like a bunch of tinned strips sandwiched between Tyvek-type (non-woven polymer cloth) material.

Nevertheless, is something like [this](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=WM10-04A-ND) (in [this category](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=WM10-04A-ND), but *not* FFCs) what you're looking for?  Digi-Key doesn't seem to have 20-pin cables in-stock. [Manufacturer (Molex) link](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=ribbon_cable_jumpers&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction).

**Edit:**
If you want to go the rigid route, headers come in all shapes and sizes.  Ones explicitly for this application I've heard them called double-level, mezzanine, but Digi-Key has them filed under [board spacers/stackers](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=1442852), though of the 4900 they "carry", 4 are in-stock.

For prototyping male/female 0.100" headers can be nice.

Comment: Yes Id prefer the "rigid route" if possible. I had a look at the digi-key link but there were only 2 items with images http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=924217-24-20-I-ND I don't see how one of these will work? I also googled "double-level mezzanine" but it didn't yeild anything relevant.

Comment: It's just like a standard 0.100" header but with an additional plastic spacer.  More pictures at the mfc website (their docs seem to be down): http://www.tycoelectronics.com/catalog/bin/TE.Connect?C=10078&M=FEAT&P=&U=&BML=10576%2C17560%2C17540%2C17745&LG=1&LBOX=2339  What you use is highly dependent on the mechanical package you're fitting it into (if any).  If this is a 1-off/prototype thing, you could use a standard male/female header (a la Arduino) to allow easy removal/replacement.

Comment: Ya.. I just dont see how you would easily attach this to a cable. What I really would like is something similar to a IDC box header to solder on to GLCD, except obviously it would need to be a single row of pins (the standard Arduino type would probably work), and then some matching connector that can be crimped onto ribbon cable. Yes I know Im lazy... but I would like some simple and neat.

Comment: Does it have to be removable?  Do you want a rigid connection or flexible one?

Comment: Removable would be good, but not essential, I just don't want to have to be solder ribbon cable directly to the GLCD or some connector.